# How does the RVIZ marker work and how can I turn it off?

Tags: ros, rviz, cartographer, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm having an Intel Aero Ready to Flight Drone with Ubuntu 16.04 installed. It uses Cartographer for SLAM and RVIZ for visualization. When using the tool, I see on RVIZ, there are some markers is drawn during the flight. The marker is a green-red-blue-axis (look like an x-y-z graph) with coordinate on top. I notice it usually drop the marker at the following situation:

- When started (initial position), so the marker always be (0,0)
- When there is a change on the path (observe an obstacle and change the path). It will increase the second number to (0,1), (0,2)
- When completed the objective/goal (moved to the designated position). A marker is also dropped (0,3)

Can I ask what the coordinate mean? Why, in my case, only the second number increased? And what if I do not want to observe those markers, how can I turn it off?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327556/how-does-the-rviz-marker-work-and-how-can-i-turn-it-off?/) by [ngocdp](https://answers.ros.org/users/43831/ngocdp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-07-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [guoxins](https://answers.ros.org/users/43895/guoxins/) on 2019-07-03**:
I encountered the same problem and here is the screenshot (https://ibb.co/1dtC12g). Clearly, you can see there are coordinate along the trajectory.
What I understood now is that RVIZ will subscribe the topic called submap_list that is published by Cartographer to present the map. However, there is a list of submaps being generated as the robot moves and each submap has a version number as well as its pose. The "Displays" panel has no options for one to turn off that number only unless one turn off all the submaps.
It's neat to know how many submaps have been generated with current setup but it looks better to me if without the numbers. Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

RViz has a "Displays" panel that has a list all the things you are seeing.
You can tick/untick the display types to see/unsee them in the main window.
Take a look at http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/UserGuide for more info.

Regarding your other question, it would be better to ask them in a different question.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2019-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ngocdp](https://answers.ros.org/users/43831/ngocdp/) on 2019-07-03**:
Thank you for your answer. We will look at the panel and the guide to see if we can turn it off.

By referring to other question, do you mean these 2 questions? "What the coordinate mean? Why, in my case, only the second number increased?"

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2019-07-04**:
@ngocdp yes, I was referring to those 2 questions.
If my answer solves your problem, please mark it as "correct"